# Where memberpress plugin saves the membership details, if I install memberpress plugin in my WordPress site?

Tags: wordpress

If I install memberpress plugin on my wordpress website, where the membership details will get saved ? Will it use wordpress database or will it use different database ?

Comment: Why don't you just install it and check your database?

Answer (score 1):

MemberPress plugin details are stored in separate tables inside your WordPress database with the prefix `mepr_` after your WordPress's table prefix `wp_`.

Here are the MemberPress (v1.3.6) tables as of this writing.

```
wp_mepr_jobs
wp_mepr_members
wp_mepr_subscriptions
wp_mepr_tax_rate_locations
wp_mepr_tax_rates
wp_mepr_transactions
```

Answer (score 1):

This is documented quite well in their user manual also.

> We use many of the built in WordPress tables, and we also add a few additional tables as well.

Source: https://docs.memberpress.com/article/219-where-is-data-stored